# How would an increased mean affect a mean parameterized integral?

Tags: mean, expected-value

Suppose we have an unknown R.V with CDF $F(X,\mu) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x) $ such that $F(0,\mu) =0 $ and $F(B,\mu) = 1$, where $B$ is a constant and $\mu$ is the mean of the underlying R.V.

Now define an integral as:

$$\int_0^{g(\mu)} F(x,\mu) dx\,, $$

where $g(\mu) \le B$ is the upper bound of the integral and itself is a function of $\mu$, and $0\le g(\mu) \le B$.

**Question:** Now if $\mu$ increases, **does the integral necessarily increase?**

**Attempt:** My hunch is it's ambiguous. This can be seen from taking derivative w.r.t $\mu$ which gives:

$$F(g(\mu),\mu)\frac{\partial g(\mu)}{\partial \mu} + \int_0^{g(\mu)} \frac{\partial F(x,\mu)}{\partial \mu} dx \,. $$

Northing confirmative from my perspective.

**In particular**, let $g(\mu)$ be defined as follows:

$$g(\mu) = \beta \left( \mu + \int_0^{g(\mu)} F(x,\mu) dx \right) \,,$$

where $0<\beta\le 1$. Will  $g(\mu)$ surely increase if I increase $\mu$?

Comment: Since you specify nothing of any import about $g$, $dg(\mu)/d\mu$ can be arbitrarily large and negative even when $F(g(\mu),\mu)$ is close to $1$, so the answer has to be "of course not." If this problem is derived from a practical situation you face, is there any additional information that could provide a lower bound for the derivative of $g$?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I'm sorry I missed the condition that $g(\mu)$ must be within $[0,B]$

Comment: That condition provides no control at all over the derivative of $g$.  It could even be unbounded within that interval.

Comment: ok, let me formulate the problem a little bit more.

Comment: @whuber I have added an equation as condition. I tried to take derivatives w.r.t $\mu$ on both sides and in the end I'm still facing an ambiguous function.

Comment: Did you really mean to define $g$ in terms of itself?

Comment: That's the equation I got unfortunately.